# Should I keep separate the capital used by my two businesses?

Tags: small-business, self-employment

I have two kinds of business. I sell stationery and pants. Each business has it own capital. But I have trouble with the stationery business capital – some bad credits happened in the business.  So, I have not enough money to buy new product.

Besides that, I have a big capital in selling pants. Should I use this capital to help the stationery business, or still keep it separate and seek a loan to improve the stationery business?

Comment: How formal is the business structure that you're operating under? If it's just two separate ways that you make money, then making this kind of transfer is not bad but it is worth tracking in case the stationery business model is not profitable. If you have actually set up independent business entities (LLC, Corp, etc.) for these, then that complicates the matter.

Comment: for stationary it just a minishop. and for pants i sell it by order so zero loss.

Comment: Right... but how do you *own* the two businesses? When you file taxes, do you file your personal taxes with the businesses connected to yours, or do your businesses file taxes separately? Also, what country?

Comment: in my country Indonesia there is no tax for minishop(home shop) its like garage sale. Both of my business is free tax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional comment you gave, I would recommend that you keep the capital from the businesses separate as much as possible.

It sounds like you won't get into any trouble *legally* if you make 'loans' or transfers of capital from one business into the other. But I would suggest that you keep detailed records of any transfers that you do make.

The reason why is that in any business, it is important to know the economics of how your business makes money. If you find yourself making transfers repeatedly, then your business model may be bad. Even if your transfers are only to deal with the cost of poor customers, it could still mean that your business model needs to be adjusted.

But if it's a question of the timing of cash flows, then there's really nothing wrong with taking some of the money from your successful pants operation and building up more working capital in your stationery shop.

Comment: that's right the important thing is the cash flow.